# How do I see the source code from packages I use in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

With regards to java projects in netbeans, how do I see the source code from the classes/packages I am importing?

I have read previous posts saying I need the src.zip file. I downloaded the netbeans-8.0.2-201411181905-src.zip file from https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.0.2/zip.html.

As a practice I googled the "String" class, and saw that it should be under java.lang.object. However, I do not see a java.lang.object folder in the src.zip file (there is lots of source code but I don't know how to navigate it effectively). Is this the wrong version? My netbeans dose say 8.2 at the top of the application.

I also tried clicking through the JAR files within the netbeans libraries/JDK folder in the project window. Again, lots of code but I feel I couldn't effectively navigate it if I was looking for a specific class.

I need to be able to quickly view source code from any packages or classes I may be working with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Having downloaded **src.zip**, you need to configure it in NetBeans:

- Select **Tools > Java Platforms**.
- Select the JDK for which you are adding the source in the **Platforms** panel.
- Click the **Sources** tab, then click the **Add JAR/Folder...** button.
- Navigate to **src.zip** and click the **Add JAR/Folder** button.

  [image: Add Source]
- Finally, click **Close** to close the **Java Platform Manager** dialog.

Then you should be able to view the source of that JDK. To check:

- In your Java source, place the cursor on any JDK class (e.g. `String`), or any of its methods or constructors.
- Right click, and from the context menu select **Navigate > Go to Source** and you should be redirected to the appropriate position within the source of the JDK class. Alternatively, press **Ctrl + Shift + B**.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a maven project, in `Projects` go to the `Dependencies`, right click on the library and choose `Download Sources`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

To sum up this experience, searching for the class name in the netbeans search bar and clicking the desired class opens the source code file. Right clicking this file's tab and clicking "Select in projects" option exposes the exact file it is stored in within the JDK.

Also projects.apache.org, http://jboss.org/projects, and https://projects.apache.org/ are useful places to find java source code.